# Change the data source in a webform that’s being opened via a MenuItemClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I’m new to `ASP.NET` and `C#` and am struggling with changing the data source in a webform that’s being opened via a `MenuItemClick` event in the master page. I want the data source of the form being opened to be based on two values in the currently open form: `txtClientFileCode` and `txtWOJob`. The form will open in edit mode. I’ve found many examples but none involving stored procedures.

Here's the `SqlDataSource` and `MenuItemClick`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceWU" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringWU %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringWU.ProviderName %>"            
        SelectCommand="spWriteUpSel" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="spWriteUpUpd" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        InsertCommand="spWriteUpIns" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"            
        DeleteCommand="spWriteUpDel" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">


protected void mnuMainMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Item.Value)
        {
            case "QuickView":
                Response.Write("QuickView");
                Response.Redirect("~/QuickView");
                break;
            case "WriteUp":
                Response.Write("WriteUp");
                Response.Redirect("~/WriteUp");
                break;
```

Any advice / examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are those SP contain parameters & have you know to use `InsertParameters`, `UpdateParameters`, `SelectParameters` & `DeleteParameters` in `SqlDataSource`? Also what kind of examples you're tried then?

Comment: I've tried several examples various posts. I have the 'Parameters in the ASP.NET file:

Comment: SqlDataSourceWU.ConnectionString = "<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringWU %>";
            SqlDataSourceWU.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataSourceWU.SelectCommand = "spWriteUpUpd";
            SqlDataSourceWU.SelectParameters.Add("txtClientFileCode", txtClientFileCode.Text);
            SqlDataSourceWU.SelectParameters.Add("txtWOJob", txtWOJob.Text);
            
            fvWriteUp.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSourceWU";
            fvWriteUp.DataBind();

Comment: So I’m able to save the value of the two textboxes using Session["sesClientFileCode"] = txtClientFileCode.Text; and Session["sesWOJob"] = txtWOJob.Text; in the current form’s FormView DataBound event but where in the form that’s being opened should I assign a SELECT clause to the SelectCommand and how to bind?